# How can i replace whole HTML string with another HTML string using JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i want to ask how can i replace whole attribute with JS. I need to replace this:

```
<div class="content twitter-container twitter-tab active" id="panel2-3">
  <div id="ember1069" class="ember-view tse-scrollable">
    <div class="tse-scrollbar" style="display: block;">
      <div class="drag-handle" style="top: 2px; height: 81px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tse-scroll-content" style="width: 374px; height: 836px;">
      <div class="tse-content">
        <div id="ember1087" class="ember-view"><!----></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this:

```
<div class="content twitter-container twitter-tab active" id="panel2-3" aria-hidden="false">
  <div id="ember1123" class="ember-view tse-scrollable">
    <div class="tse-scrollbar" style="display: none;">
      <div class="drag-handle" style="top: 2px; height: 81px;"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="tse-scroll-content" style="width: 374px; height: 836px;">
    <div class="chat">
      <iframe id="chat_embed" src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/?????????/chat?darkpopout" scrolling="no" width="374" height="836" frameborder="0">&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;br /&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to locate first script in website and change it with second one. I tried something like this:

```
 (function() {
 'use strict';
const htmlString = `
<div class="content twitter-container twitter-tab active" id="panel2-3" aria-hidden="false">
 <div id="ember1123" class="ember-view tse-scrollable">
  <div class="tse-scrollbar" style="display: none;">
    <div class="drag-handle" style="top: 2px; height: 81px;"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="tse-scroll-content" style="width: 374px; height: 836px;">
  <div class="chat">
    <iframe id="chat_embed" src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/?????????/chat?darkpopout" scrolling="no" width="374" height="836" frameborder="0">&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;br /&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
    </iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 `;

document.querySelector('.parent').innerHTML = htmlString;
var myvar = '<div class="parent">'+
'  <div class="content twitter-container twitter-tab active" id="panel2-3">'+
'    <div id="ember1069" class="ember-view tse-scrollable">'+
'      <div class="tse-scrollbar" style="display: block;">'+
'        <div class="drag-handle" style="top: 2px; height: 81px;"></div>'+
'      </div>'+
'      <div class="tse-scroll-content" style="width: 374px; height: 836px;">'+
'        <div class="tse-content">'+
'          <div id="ember1087" class="ember-view"><!----></div>'+
'        </div>'+
'      </div>'+
'    </div>'+
'  </div>'+
'</div>';
})();
```

I'm not owner of web where i want to use it. I want to inject script which can locate first HTML string and replace it with my own HTML string. (Already got plugin which can inject JS to websites just need help with code).

It's user script for Tampermonkey Chrome/Mozilla extension.

Comment: What's wrong with using `document.querySelector('.parent').innerHTML = htmlString;`?

Comment: You are wanting to inject html from one website into another website that you do not own?  That's called Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and is a security concern that browsers should prevent you from doing.  Unless you are talking about some sort of user script you are trying to write, but I do not see that mentioned in the context of the question.

Comment: Wait, what is a purpose behind wanting to inject element in another page's element? This sounds like you are phishing. If you are simply reusing rest of the structure make it static by getting the rest of HTML and change that part in your HTML.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith It's probably just a browser extension.

Comment: @Olian04 sounds reasonable, did not think of that.

Comment: Yes its user script that i want to use with "Tampermonkey" extension.

Comment: I do not see class `parent` in the original markup.  I do see id `panel2-3`.  Try changing your operation to being `querySelector('#panel2-3').parentNode.innerHTML ...`

Comment: @FuxikNah please edit the question to make mention of that, :)

Comment: @Taplar you mean like this? `document.querySelector('#panel2-3').parentNode.innerHTML = htmlString;
var myvar = '<div class="parent">'+`

Comment: Sure, that would find the element by the id, go up to it's immediate parent, and change that parent's html.